# How define a Traverse for neo4j with Python?

Tags: python, neo4j, neo4j.py

I need to traverse a neo4j graph using Python27.

From the manual I've seen that I can define a **Traversal** and include a **Evaluator** and I got something similar to that.

```
def my_evaluator(path):
    if (path.end['type'] == 'STOP') or (path.end['type'] == 'BUS_STOP'):
        return Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE
    else:
        return Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE

def get_passengers_with_bus_stop(db, start_node):
    nodes = []

    traverser = db.traversal()\
        .relationships('STOPS_AT', INCOMING)\
        .relationships('HAS_BEEN', OUTGOING)\
        .evaluator(my_evaluator)\
        .traverse(start_node)

    # Name
    for n in traverser.nodes.iterator():
        nodes.append(n['name'])

    return nodes
```

But from the list of nodes returned I want to exclude the first node and sometimes stop at some Deepth.

How can I do that with the **Traversals** that defines de neo4j manual?

At sometimes I've found a presentation that explains another way to define **Traversals** but this don't runs properly, I receive and error from Python. Do I need something else installed?

```
class Users(neo4j.Traversal): # Traversals ! queries in Neo4j
    types = [ neo4j.INCOMING.WORKS_AS,neo4j.OUTGOING.BELONGS_TO]
    order = neo4j.BREADTH_FIRST
    stop = neo4j.STOP_AT_END_OF_GRAPH
    returnable = neo4j.RETURN_ALL_BUT_START_NODE
```

How can I define a Traverse for neo4j with Python to:

- Exclude the first node
- Stop at some deepth

Maybe I should use **subtraversals**? How can I define them?

More specifically I want to define a **Traversal** over this graph to go from the node "I'm" here to node "-1" or node "+1" alone. The graph defines de direction of the relations and the names of them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can chain multiple evaluators to achieve this. To skip the start node, add an evaluator that looks something like this:

```
def exclude_start_node(path):
    if len(path) == 0:
        return Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE

    return Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE
```

And to stop at some given depth, something like this:

```
def stop_at_depth(depth):
    def evaluator(path):
        if len(path) >= depth:
            return Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_PRUNE

        return Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE
    return evaluator
```

You would use it like this:

```
t = db.traverse().evaluator(stop_at_depth(5)).evaluator(exclude_start_node)
```

Note how both of these traversers use INCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE where they don't "apply". When chaining evaluators, the most restrictive evaluator will win. So if any evaluator says "EXCLUDE", the current node will be excluded, and if any evaluator says "PRUNE", traversal will stop down the current path.

Also, as of last week, the latest versions of the neo4j-embedded bindings let you execute cypher queries. You might want to look into that, as it may be a much easier way to write the queries you are looking at.

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/python-embedded-reference-cypher.html